# Default node selector

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

**Use case**

Let's say I've got 3 different node pools: `default`, `kafka` and `team-a`. I want to make sure that only kafka relevant deployments and stuff like daemonsets or kubernetes system services run on this node pool. I do so by simply adding a node selector to my kafka deployments, so that it can only be scheduled on the kafka nodepool:

```
nodeSelector:
  cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: kafka
```

**The problem**

When I have further deployments or statefulsets which **do not** have any node selector specified they might get scheduled on that kafka nodepool. Instead I want all other deployments without nodeselector to be scheduled inside of my default nodepool.

**Worded as generic question**

How can I make sure that all deployments & statefulsets without a node selector will be scheduled inside of a specific nodepool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `taint` for statefulset or `pod`. Follow: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be to specify the node pool for every deployment and statefulset.